# New line in tweet with tweetbot in php?

Tags: php, html, twitter, escaping, encode

I'm trying to write a tweet with `twitterbot in php`...
i would put inside a new line (`\n` `<br>`) but doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
// OAuth To Twitter
require_once 'twitteroauth.php'; //INSIDE IT ther's a require_once OAuth.php file

$one_br= urlencode("\n");

// Do NOT Share
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "YOUR_APP_KEY");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "YOUR_APP_SECRET");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "YOUR_ACCOUNT_OAUTH_TOKEN");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "YOUR_ACCOUNT_OAUTH_SECRET");
// Post To Twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test %0a di prova'.$one_br.'#tweet automatico- Test 5'));
// All Done Here
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Test %0a di prova%0A#tweet automatico- Test 5
```

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This way work with me:

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => '
Hi xxxx,

How are you today?

-

Just leave empty line